# How to silence console.log from third party iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, iframe, embed

Currently, I'm developing a web app using NEXT.js. The deal is that I'm working with a third party iframe which is displaying lots (hundreds) of console.logs. I just want to “mute” the outputs for the iframe.

My code is just and <iframe> with the embed link.

I'm aware there a some similar questions, but none of them are related to third party iframes.

Hope anyone can help a bit here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but if it's a cross-origin frame, I don't think you can do anything about it without proxying the content through your own server<sup>1</sup> (thus making it no longer cross-origin).

You can't access the JavaScript environment of a cross-origin frame, so you can't (for instance) replace `console.log` with a do-nothing stub.

If you proxied the frame through your own server<sup>1</sup> so it wasn't cross-origin, there are several things you could do, such as injecting code as you passed it through that puts in that do-nothing stub, or doing that client-side. But if you keep it as a cross-origin frame, I think you're stuck with the logs.

---

<sup>1</sup> *loading it from your server, and having your server request the content from the origin server then pass that content back to your page*

Comment: Understood! Is there a way to block in any way the users to open dev tools or similar (so they can´t see the console.logs). Because I have seen some websites that when you try to open the dev tools, the debuggers stops the page.

Comment: @pacorisas - Not as far as I know. You can block *some* ways of opening devtools (such as handling Ctrl+Shift+I and F12 and right-click), but you can't block all of them, the user can always open devtools via the browser menu.